# remote origin already exists for github

Tags: git, github

"Error: remote origin already exists" when trying to import my python project that I prepared using git from terminal to github
i am getting the error.

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+remote+origin+already+exists

Answer (score 8):

The error `fatal: remote origin already exists` is caused when you attempt to create a link to a remote repository called “origin” when a remote link with that name is already configured.

The solution is to update the URL of the remote repository with the name “origin” to the URL of the remote repository you want to add, instead of trying to create a new remote repository with that name.

You can do that with this command:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your/repository`

Source: https://www.datree.io/resources/git-error-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists